# If the user visits my flask website from his/her email; how can I get his/her email address?

Tags: python, flask

If the user has a mail message containing a link to my webapp which is built in flask. The user clicks the link and visits my site.

The question now: how can I configure my flask app to detect that this user has visited the site via email?

Answer (score 3):

You can configure the URL as a campaign. So for example:

```
https://www.example.com/?utm_source=newsletter&utm_medium=email
```

You can build the link here: https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder/

Then in your app, you can get the `utm_source` and `utm_medium` like so:

```
from flask import request

source = request.args.get('utm_source')
medium = request.args.get('utm_medium')
```

It also works with Google Analytics if you have G Analytics installed.

Comment: As an aside, marketing platforms like Mailchimp and Sendgrid typically does this for you automatically. They have an option to transform any URLs inside the email to be appended with `utm_source` and `utm_medium` query string

Comment: Thanks a lot Edward :) Your answer is really fruitful.

Comment: @MohammedAliIsmail No problem! Please accept the answer if it answered your question. Thanks